# Digital signal processing with c++/c

Tags: signals, digital

How i can start digital signal processing in c++ or c?
if any one can refer me a good websites and books and i need to know if there is any libraries in c++/c to design a filter and segment the signal...

Comment: Maybe look into GNURadio https://www.gnuradio.org

Comment: Removed the tag <[processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info)>. [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For designing filters you can use Matlab, design the filter, and then extract poles and zeros and use them in your C code.